# Final variables in method

Tags: java, access-modifiers

In java, if a method has a final variable (not static), and If I am calling the method multiple times, can the final variable have different values in each call?

```
public void method1(String msg){
        final ArrayList<MessageObject> list =  method2(msg);
        // code that uses list (example just prints) 
}

method1("one")
method1("two") are two calls,
```

if method2() returns different lists for each input, is the above code valid (with respect to final modifier?)

Comment: think of the function stack when calling the method - once it's done the variable is kaput

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, absolutely. `final` *only* means that *that particular variable* can't be assigned a different value.

If you have multiple calls to the method (whether via recursion or multiple threads) those are entirely separate variables.

Answer (score 1):

**Question 1**:  In java, if a method has a final variable (not static), and If I am calling the method multiple times, can the final variable have different values in each call?

**Answer 1**: Yes, the final variable can have different values in each call.

**Question 2**: if method2() returns different lists for each input, is the above code valid (with respect to final modifier?)

**Answer 2**: I completely don't understand this question.

Comment: Actually, your Answer 1 answers Question 2.
That's just for the code snippet I was working on.
+1